# PHP/MySQL/JS: Use JS index to INSERT INTO row with that index

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, arrays

I got a variable:

```
var items = $('.ui-selected', this).map(function() {
  return $(this).index();
}).get();
```

That's giving me an array of dynamic numbers. For example:

```
[0]
[0, 1]
```

So I want to pass that array to PHP. There I want to use these numbers to `INSERT INTO` these specific columns. So when i get 0 and 1 in the array I want to write a value in column 1 and 2. To pass that value I tried this:

```
//JS
items = items.join(',')
$.post('/save.php', { 'items': items })

//PHP
$items = $_POST['items'];
$items = explode(',', $items);
```

But do MySQL columns got the same indexes as JS? So is the first column index 0?

Comment: The short answer is 'yes'. The longer answer is that you do not need to know the MySQL column index.

Comment: So how would you solve this, if not with the column index?

Comment: `explode` won't parse JSON data.

Comment: 1st - does your table have more than 2 columns? 2nd - If it does, which columns should get the data being posted? 3rd - without seeing the details of the code you're trying to use to insert the data we would only be guessing.

Comment: My table got 6 columns. As I said, the JS index array got different values. So sometimes it got `[1, 2]` or `[4, 5, 6]`, that's changing. And I want the data to get posted into these columns.